# Simulate Data (X,Y) that are Quadratically Related to one another

Tags: r, simulation, quadratic

I'm looking to simulate a dataset with two variables (X,Y) where the relation between these variables is quadratic (some version of an inverted U). Is there a way to do this in R? Understandably, the exact shape of the relationship can differ, as can the unique effect of the quadratic term over and above the linear term. In an ideal world, the simulation would fix the total explained Y variance and the unique variance of the quadratic term in the population.

I’m looking to create something like this: 1000 pairs of XY, with Y having a normal distribution with Mn=0, SD=1 and X being as close to normal distribution and as close to Mn=0, SD=1 as possible. Total variance explained by linear and quadratic term weak (R^2 = .05) [by total variance, I mean if I regress Y onto X and X^2, the multiple R^2 = .05]. I don’t have any data for the example because these are to be simulated; the question is borderline Cross Validated or Stack Overflow, but given the desire to do in R, it seems to fit best here.

Thanks for any help.

---

After looking some more, stumbled across the simstudy package, which allows for some flexibility in creating simulated quadratic relationships:

```
library(psych)
library(simstudy)
#From: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/simstudy/vignettes/simstudy.html, and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simstudy/simstudy.pdf 
def <- defData(varname = "nr", dist = "nonrandom", formula = 7, id = "idnum")
def <- defData(def, varname = "uni", dist = "uniform", formula = "10;20")
ddef <- defData(def, varname = "X1_q", formula = "nr + uni * 2", variance = 8)

set.seed(333)
theta1 = c(.2, 0.35, .7, .8, .7, .35, .2) 
knots <- c(.3, .5, .7) #quantiles
viewSplines(knots = knots, theta = theta1, degree = 3)

dt <- genData(1000, ddef)
dt <- genSpline(dt = dt, newvar = "Y_q",
                predictor = "X1_q", theta = theta1,
                knots = knots, degree = 3,
                noise.var = .25)
psych::describe (dt)
hist(dt$X1_q)
hist(dt$Y_q)
plot(dt$X1_q, dt$Y_q)
dt$X1_q_sq <- dt$X1_q * dt$X1_q
summary(lm(Y_q~ X1_q + X1_q_sq, data = dt))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```r
X <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)            # simulate from the normal distribution
Y <- X^2 + runif(1000, -0.1, 0.1) # make it squared +/- a little bit
```

Not sure if you wanted to simulate noise, but you can increase/decrease the noise level by changing the last two arguments in the `runif` function. The further away from 0 the more noise there will be

You can see their relationship by plotting them:

```r
plot(X, Y)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, RAB. That is close but the challenge for me has been adding "noise" in a precise way. Adding uniform randomness with the runif isn't quite ideal - most importantly, it is hard to add realistic randomness that results in a weak effect. Even changing to -1 to 1 in the runif results in multiple-R^2 of around .84.

Comment: what is the point of doing this? Like, what is the end goal? Trying to simulate (which sort of implies some aspect of randomness) data that super specifically conforms to these odd rules is nigh on impossible imho